# Switch from Resharper 4.0 keyboard bindings to 5.0 keyboard bindings

Tags: c#-4.0, resharper

I found two cheatsheets for reshaper shortcuts:

4.0 defaults
http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/docs/ReSharper40DefaultKeymap2.pdf

5.0 defaults
http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/docs/ReSharper50DefaultKeymap_VS_scheme.pdf

I have resharper 7.1. installed on my machine. By default my resharper seems to be using the 4.0 shortcuts. Please let me know what can I do to ensure 5.0 shortcuts scheme is used by resharper on my machine.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

> Resharper > Options > Visual Studio Integration > [Ensure that the 'Visual Studio' keyboard scheme is selected] > Click 'Apply Scheme'

Comment: thank you! :)I contacted Resharper support as well and they came back with the same response.